# fprintf is being ignored

Tags: c++

I'm inserting number, if this number does not equals number that need to be - program will crash, that's what i need. It's some sort of security things

but... when i launch the program, fprintf is being skipped

What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>;
#include <string>;
#pragma warning(disable: 4996);
using namespace std;
char record_book_number[8] = "";
struct cipher {
    char cipher_type[1];
    string source_info;
    string ciphered_info;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    FILE* config = fopen("D:/Docs/rec_book_number.txt", "w");
    cout << "Input your Record Book's number\n";
    fprintf(config, "%d\n", record_book_number);
    char buffer[10];
    int id_buffer;
    while (1)
    {
        if (!fgets(buffer, 10, config)) { break; }

        id_buffer = atoi(buffer);
        if (1848245 == id_buffer) { printf("yes"); continue; }
    }
    cipher type;
    cout << "Select cipher type:\n 1. Caesar\n 2. Vigenere\n\n\n ";
    cin >> type.cipher_type;
    ifstream file("source.txt");
    cout << "Input line to cipher: \n";
}
`
```

Comment: please only tag the language you are using. C and C++ are two different languages. I removed the C++ tag, because code looks like C

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number there is a `cout <<` in the code.

Comment: yep, sorry, i'm just usually using both

Comment: then it is definitely no C ;)

Comment: it's mix of? at least i guess so

Comment: Symbol used `record_book_number`, but not defined. Also this doesn't look like proper use of `fprintf`. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: the line between C and C++ may appear to be fuzzy because you can and you are using C io in the code. However, actually it is rather clear, `cout` is C++ and cannot compile as C, hence the code is C++ and in C++ you can do lots of things that you cannot do in C and vice versa. It avoids lots of complication and confusion to accept that they are two different languages (even though they are close relatives)

Comment: Sure, https://yaso.su/vkj7pO2l -- full code
upd: in question

Comment: the full example code should be in the question

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should check whether `fopen` succeeds,  Your current code will likely crash if it doesn't.

Comment: You're reading too much into `type.cipher_type` - it only has room for the null terminator, not for any actual contents. Thus, your program has undefined behaviour and anything can happen. (Why is it not an integer?)

Comment: `#include <iostream>;`: the `;` is definitely wrong and so is the `;` after the line with `#pragma` and `fprintf(config, "%d\n", record_book_number);` should be `fprintf(config, "%s\n", record_book_number);`, your compiler most likely warned you about this.

Comment: You code doesn't make much sense, you write `record_book_number` into the file, but `record_book_number` is an empty string, because ylu never put anything into it. You read from an empty file that you've just created. Please [edit] and tell us what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using fprintf correctly. You must pass the file, format string, then data to it. See the [reference here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/).

Try replacing

```
fprintf(config, record_book_number);
```

with

```
fprintf(config, "%d\n", record_book_number);
```

-- Update --

Okay, there is a lot that needs fixing. record_book_number is a string, but its value is never set. So the format string should be "%s\n" however writing an uninitialised string is very dangerous and could crash your program. Also your file is created for writing so you cannot read from it using fgets.

Can you explain what you're expecting this code to do, because it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: nope, no result :(

Comment: You'll have to give us some information if you want us to help you.

Comment: In addition why are you mixing C and C++ file handling functions? This way lies madness!

Comment: I'm inserting number, if this number does not equals number that need to be - program will crash, that's what i need. It's some sort of security things

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't make sense. There are a lot of things wrong with your code. For starters choose C or C++ and use one, do not mix them. fopen with the "w" flag will create a new empty file for writing, erasing any existing contents. What is the 1848245 magic number?

Comment: Well... This number does not have much sense, just magic number.